# Youtube search API results not displaying in the EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, youtube-data-api

I am implementing YouTube Search API in my Website, when I am calling the api from my route the results are returned but the page is rendered while the results are being computed, I guess because of the asynchronous behavior.

My route through which I am calling the API:

```js
router.get('/video/results/:search_query', middleware.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    query = req.params.search_query;
    console.log(query);
    var dataFinal;
    var resp = youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: query,
        type: 'video'
    },function (err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
            res.json({
                status: "error"
            });
        }
        if (data) {
           // console.log(typeof data);
            dataFinal = data;
           //  return res.json({
           //      status: "ok",
           //      data: data
           //  });

            console.log(data);
            //res.render('resultsVideo',{results:data})
        }
    });
    res.render('resultsVideo',{data:dataFinal})

});
```

Please tell me how can I call the API and use the results in my EJS file to display.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function callback to get the desired result.

```
router.get('/video/results/:search_query', middleware.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    query = req.params.search_query;
    console.log(query);
    var dataFinal;
    function resp() = youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: query,
        type: 'video'
    },function (err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
            res.json({
                status: "error"
            });
        }
        if (data) {
           // console.log(typeof data);
            return data;
           //  return res.json({
           //      status: "ok",
           //      data: data
           //  });

            console.log(data);
            //res.render('resultsVideo',{results:data})
        }
    });
    res.render('resultsVideo',{data:resp()})

});
```